# Why the length of the zigzag curve approximating the circle does not approach the length of the circle?

Tags: limits, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

I recently bumped into this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4) which asks why $\pi=4$ is wrong.

[image]

And some answers(see the answer of user TCL, for example) stated that this has to do with functions and their derivatives.

Their answers were something like this:

Let $F_n(x)$ be a sequence of curves (the zigzag curves in the above picture) that approach $g(x)$ as n tends to $\infty$.

And $g(x)$ the curve that represents the circle.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x) = g(x).$$

Does not imply

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F'_n(x) = g'(x).$$

And lengths has to do with derivatives($\int \sqrt{f'(x)+1} \,  dx$), therefore convergence of two curves does not mean convergence of their length.

And based upon my understanding of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/524634/243846):

[image]

the condition that the function should satisfy for the above implication to hold is that it has to be a continuous function,but the curve(see the linked question) approximating the circle it is not continuous.

Is my understanding correct?

Does convergence of two **continuous** functions implies the convergence of their derivatives?

If this is the case, then why the function that approximates the circles is not continuous?

I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194153/when-converges-of-function-imply-converges-of-derivative), But I don't know if its related to my question about continuity?

Comment: what derivatives?

Comment: @dREaM If you have a curve that is given by $f(x)$, its length is computed by $\int \sqrt{f'(x)+1}   dx$

Comment: there are continuous functions that are nowhere differentiable.

Comment: What are "two continous functions"? Your question seems unclear

Comment: @MichaelGaluza If $F(x), g(x)$ are continuous, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x) = g(x)$, Does that imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} F'_n(x) = g'(x)$?

Comment: Let $F_n(x)=\frac1n\sin(nx)$. Then clearly $F_n(x)\to0$ but $F_n'(x)=\cos(nx)\not\to0$.

Comment: I would like to know why my question was downvoted, downvoter can you explain?

Comment: For one, you are confusing the fact that the functional $\gamma\mapsto\ell(\gamma)$ is not continuous (for the uniform norm) wih the fact that one applies $\ell$ to continuous functions.

Comment: @Did I would be pretty grateful if you clear up my confusion and misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza No, uniform convergence is not enough.  Rahul's counterexample converges uniformly.

Comment: @Strants, oh, really. Thanks

Comment: Omar: I just did. (Note that there are other misunderstandings such as, possibly, some confusion of continuity with differentiability.) Re the point underlined in my first comment, a productive approach from your part would be to explain what it is you do not understand in it. This would require to read the comment slowly and carefully, nothing more. But then, this applies already to @Emanuele's comment, which is already pretty clear and explicit and precisely stated...

Comment: @Did I know that a function is continuous when $\lim_{n \to c} f(x) = f(c)$. It is differentiable if its continuous and $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists. Every differentiable  $f$ is continuous  but the opposite is not true. This is my understanding of the concepts. Now regarding your comment, I didn't understand it at all, I'm totally unfamiliar with the concepts you're talking about.

Comment: ?? The only "concept" my first comment is mentioning is *continuity* (at two levels, continuity of $\gamma$ some function from some interval of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$, and (non-)continuity of $\ell$ some function defined on some space of differentiable functions $\gamma$).

Comment: If you take any number  of turns along N-S and E-W roads your distance won't change. But if at all there are diagonal shortcuts, your total length is thereby less, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you misunderstand Emanuele Paolini's answer. He notes the problem that $\ell$ is not a continuous function. But his $\ell$ does not refer to one of the curves, which you label $F_n$ and $g$. Instead, $\ell$ is the function that inputs a curve and outputs its length. What it means for such a "higher-order" function to be continuous or discontinuous takes some work to explain... You can try researching the topology of uniform convergence.

Comment: Alright, that's regarding Emanuele's answer, what about TCL's answer(the second Answer in the linked question)? He states that when two functions converges, this does not imply thier derivatives do. When he's talking about functions, is he talking about the functions that represent the curves or the function which "takes a curve as an input and output its lenght"?

Comment: TCL is talking about the curves. Note the sentence "let x=a(t) ... be the parameterizations of the two curves".

Comment: So based on the answer of TCL, which says that convergence of functions (those representing the curves) does not imply convergence of their derivatives(which are used in computing the length), And this is the reason why the fact that the zigzag approaches the circle does not imply that their length converge. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's correct! Still, you should be careful not to over-generalize the idea. I'm sure there are other sequences of curves where the derivatives behave very badly yet the lengths still miraculously converge.

Comment: So what is the neccessary condition that must be satisfied for the implication to holds true?

Comment: Well, I doubt that there is any reasonable necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac1x\sin x^2$, $g(x)\equiv0$.
Then
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\sin x^2+\frac1x\cdot 2x\cos x^2,
$$
which has no limit at infinity, while derivative of $g$ is 0.

Comment: I have edit my question, So if you wish to edit in response.