# $f_n\xrightarrow{L^p}f \implies f_n'\xrightarrow{L^p}f'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of function that is differentiable. such that $f_n\xrightarrow{L^p}f$ converges. I was wondering if $f_n'\xrightarrow{L^p}f'$. So far I could only find [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194164/340973) but it doesn't really apply here I think.

Comment: Of course not. If $f$ is measurable and non continuous, there is a sequence of $\mathcal C^\infty $ function $(f_n)$ s.t. $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$. So, if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ and $(f_n)$ differentiable, there is no reason for $f$ to be differntiable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Example: $p=1$, $f_n$ and $f$ in $L^1[0,1]$ let be given by

$$ f_n(x) =x^n , \quad f(x)=0.$$

Then

$$||f_n-f||_1 = \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0,$$

as $ n \to \infty,$ but

$$||f_n'-f'||_1 = 1$$

for all $n$.